# Read from file, output only display one line

Tags: c, file, loops, io

I want to read some data from file newdata.dat which has 5 data in it. My program should output all of 5 data:

323 Bailey, Bill    922.00

163 Bean, Jim      2023.00

183 Daniels, Jack  3932.00

123 Doe, John      1022.00

121 Smith, Sam      512.00

but my output only display 1 line of data. Please advice? Thanks.

Ellie

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main () {

/* Define Structure */
/* ---------------- */

struct emp
{
    int     id_num;     /* employee number */
    float   salary;     /* employee salary */
    char    first_name[20]; /* employee first name */
    char    last_name[30];  /* employee last name */
};


/* Declare variables */
/* ----------------- */
struct emp info[100];   /* a maximum 100 people can be stored */
FILE    *in_file_ptr:
int     i;


/* Open the input file. If error, display message and exit the program */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */
in_file_ptr = fopen("newdata.dat", "rb");
if (!in_file_ptr)
{
    printf ("\nCannot open file newdata.dat for reading.\n");
    return 1;
}


for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
    /* Read data from input file and load array struct for processing */
    fread (&info[i], sizeof(info[i]), 100, in_file_ptr);

    /* concatenate first name anda last name */     
    strcat  (info[i].last_name, info[i].first_name);

    printf ("%10i %20s %-10.2f\n", info[i].id_num, 
        info[i].last_name, info[i].salary);


    if(feof(in_file_ptr))break;

} /* end for loop */

fclose (in_file_ptr);

} /* end of  main */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does some double counting: on one hand, it performs the read 100 times; on the other hand, it instructs `fread` to read 100 records. Since the first `fread` consumes all the records that you have in the file, the loop exits on `feof` right away.

You should either read the whole thing at once, like this:

```
size_t count = fread (&info[i], sizeof(info[i]), 100, in_file_ptr);
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != count ; i++) {
    ... // no reading or checking feof here
}
```

or change `fread` to read a single record, like this:

```
if (fread (&info[i], sizeof(info[i]), 1, in_file_ptr) != 1) break;
//                                ^
```

Note that of you use `feof`, you should check it after reading and before consuming any data that you have read. You should also check the return value of `fread`.

Comment: I didn't realize that my code does double counting. I'm new in C, and this is for my class assignment. I just fixed it as per your suggestion, it works now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: on my output data there is 1 extra data output >> 0 0 0. Can you tell me why is it happen?

Comment: The zeros are gone now, thank you! I'm learning C recently, and I need to understand more the basic. Can you suggest any book for me?

Answer (score 0):

strongly suggest using fgets() to read only line at a time.

The field sizes in the file do not match the field sizes in the struct, 
so directly reading to info[x] will not work.

use fgets() to read in a buffer

(where that buffer is long enough to hold the maximum line length (plus some extra room)

then parse the fields out of the buffer using (for instance) strtok()

then converting the float value using something like strtod(),

then assigning that value to the float field.

For the char fields, after parsing,

use strcpy() to place the strings into the fields,

exit loop when fgets returns null